# how to use php to display chr() in html

Tags: php, chr

i would like to use the chr function to display abc++ in code block but i do not know how to incorporate the chr function in this block of html code.

```
       <?php 
      for ($x = 65 ; $x <= 90; $x ++){
      echo "<div class='black-box'>
        <div class='letter'>
        chr($x); <sub class='small'>$x</sub>
        </div>          
      </div>" ;} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concatenate the PHP function or echo it to make it work, so this is my code

```
<?php
for ($x = 65 ; $x <= 90; $x++) {
    echo "<div class='black-box'>
          <div class='letter'>";
    echo chr($x);
    echo "<sub class='small'>$x</sub>
          </div>
          </div>";
}
?>
```

---

**EDIT**
This next function, will output the same, but will be concatenated to the same echo:

```
<?php
for ($x = 65 ; $x <= 90; $x++) {
    echo "<div class='black-box'>
          <div class='letter'>".chr($x)."<sub class='small'>$x</sub>
          </div>
          </div>";
}
?>
```

---

Have a look here for more info: [PHP Echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: worked thank you can you explain to me why you cancatenate

Comment: @Bogle The problem in your question, from what I know and experience with PHP, is that you can't write a function inside `"` and think that PHP will use it. You must concatenate it to the text or echo. You could write all my 3 echoes in one echo, by writing `.` before each echo closure (`;`). Look at my answer to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this: (Sorry no explaining, bad time)

```
<?php
    $x=0;
    $target = 5000;
    echo '<table style="width:50%;"><thead><tr><td style="width:50%;">Code</td><td style="width:50%;>Character</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
    while($x<$target){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$x.'</td><td>'.chr($x).'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    $x = 65;
    $target = 90;
    function displaychar($from, $to){
        $string = "<table style='width:50%;'><thead><tr><td style='width:50%;'>Code</td><td style='width:50%;'>Character</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
        while($from<=$to){
            $string=$string. '<tr><td>'.$from.'</td><td>'.chr($from).'</td></tr>';
            $from++;
        }
        $string=$string. '</tbody></table';
        return $string;
    }
    echo displaychar($x, $target);
?>
```

Comment: thank you but this code did not work. i tried to use '   '.chr($x).'    ' to display the chr function this did not work also